# Wordpress CPT (Custom Post Type) and URLS

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to develop a travel website where I have the following types of content:

- Destinations (pj: Alicante)
- Pages (ex: General information)
- Places (ex: Beach of Sant Jhon)
- Posts (ex: Tips for travel to alicante)

### **How could I get the following urls structure?**

www.miweb.com/**alicante** (*CPT Destinations*)

www.miweb.com/alicante/**general-information** (*CPT pages* with relationship with the destination)

www.miweb.com/alicante/general-information/**guide** (*CPT pages* with relationship with the destination *hierarchical*)

www.miweb.com/alicante/**beach-of-sant-jhon** (*CPT places* with relationship with the destination)

www.miweb.com/alicante/**tips-for-travel-to-alicante** (*CPT Posts*)

### **Is it possible to make this urls structure? Can you help me?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use custom post types to achieve this, you can use the parent page feature so that pages have a parent-child in the permalink structure like so:

yoursite.com/parent-page/child-page

You can also setup categories to work this way for posts and set the permalink structure for posts so that the category appears first:

yoursite.com/category/post

In this way you can avoid CPT's which are more complicated to use than the core post types.

This will only affect the front end so if you need a backend or admin setup you may still need a CPT, however you could get away with simply re-naming 'posts' or 'categories' to 'destinations'.

Comment: Hello pointydrip, thanks for your answer. This may be a solution but i need diferent custom fields on this CPTs and if i use the same CPT for all i cant get this diferent fields. There are any alternative?